# Date formatting?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am using an api with a json endpoint to grab some data.

the api returns dates that look like: `Date(1288205847730)` (so a basic javascript date object)

How do I convert that to `Thu, 28 Oct`

---

That is the generalized question that I could work from.

The actual question is I want to show `Thu, 28 Oct` format if there is more than 24 hours between now and that date,

if there is less I want to show `13 hours 8 minutes`

(note: the times used are made up and do not correspond to the time used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do without building the whole string yourself with plain javascript is

```
Date d = new Date(1288205847730); // milliseconds
d.toLocaleDateString();
```

If you want to use a library like jQuery you can find plugins that do it: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard UNIX timestamp with milliseconds, so JavaScript can process it directly:

```
var timestamp = 1288205847730;
var dateTime = new Date(timestamp); // => Wed Oct 27 2010 13:57:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

As for formatting it, I'd suggest using someone else's code since there's already plenty out there. Here's a [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+time+ago) to get you started; the first few results should get you started.

Comment: cheers, I am aware of this, my question mostly pertains to the formatting of the date once it is in the object.

Comment: I was hoping javascript would have something similar to php's date methods.

Comment: Hailwood; I updated my answer with some information on formatting dates. There are several good libraries/plugins out there that do this kind of formatting.

Comment: Hailwood: Unfortunately JavaScript doesn't have any built-in date-formatting functions like PHP. Your best bet is to Google around for a library that does what you need: http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+date+format

Answer (score 0):

Each implementation of JavaScript can differ. I recommending this article on [Working with Dates](http://www.elated.com/articles/working-with-dates/). It describes a function for formatting dates into strings.

Example:

```
var current_date = new Date ( );

var month_names = new Array ( );
month_names[month_names.length] = "January";
month_names[month_names.length] = "February";
month_names[month_names.length] = "March";
month_names[month_names.length] = "April";
month_names[month_names.length] = "May";
month_names[month_names.length] = "June";
month_names[month_names.length] = "July";
month_names[month_names.length] = "August";
month_names[month_names.length] = "September";
month_names[month_names.length] = "October";
month_names[month_names.length] = "November";
month_names[month_names.length] = "December";

var day_names = new Array ( );
day_names[day_names.length] = "Sunday";
day_names[day_names.length] = "Monday";
day_names[day_names.length] = "Tuesday";
day_names[day_names.length] = "Wednesday";
day_names[day_names.length] = "Thursday";
day_names[day_names.length] = "Friday";
day_names[day_names.length] = "Saturday";

document.write ( day_names[current_date.getDay()] );
document.write ( ", " );
document.write ( month_names[current_date.getMonth()] );
document.write ( " " + current_date.getDate() );
document.write ( " " );
document.write ( " " + current_date.getFullYear() );
```

Comment: have to give a massive LOL to how those arrays are initialised...should just use literal notation.. like month_names = [ "January", "February", "March", "...etc" ] ;

Comment: @RueTheWhirled. I agree, I was just quoting and didn't feel like rewriting the example.

Comment: Fair enuf, but felt the need to point out that's a really bad example of defining an array's values

Comment: @RTW. No problem. I didn't even take offense.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah unfortunately there isn't any decent built in date methods like php has. So short of using a library, which might be over kill, you'd have to create your own formatting function. Jordons on the right track but please don't initialise your arrays like that heh use the below

```
month_names = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November","December"];
```

Here's a list of the available date functions 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 0):

Got this one out of my toolbox.  You can mod the date obj's prototype to your specification.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
Date.prototype.toDayDateMonth = function(){
    var dayname = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]
    var monthname = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    return ( dayname[this.getDay()] + " " + this.getDate() + " " + monthname[this.getMonth()] )
}

var d1 = new Date(1288205847730);
alert(d1.toDayDateMonth());
</script>
```